# (fabric.js) Can I change a position of a character in iText for vertical writing?

Tags: fabricjs

I am Japanese, and I want to write Japanese words vertically in Fabric.js.

Japanese language has small letters, and the positions of the them are top-left corner in vertical writing.
So, I want to change the position of a small letter in iText.

I thought that I can change the position of a character by using "styles" parameter of iText, so I wrote as follows.

```
var iTextSample = new fabric.IText('h\ne\nl\nl\no', {
  left: 50,
  top: 50,
  fontFamily: 'Helvetica',
  fill: '#333',
  lineHeight: 1.1,
  styles: {
    1: {
        0: { textDecoration: 'underline',  ←★　WORK
             fontSize: 80, ←★　WORK
             top:-10, 　←★　NOT WORK
             transformMatrix: [ 1, 0, 0, 1, 18, -50 ] ←★　NOT WORK 
           },
       },
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/uemon/tLy9eqj6/77/

The 'textDecoration' and 'fontSize' worked, but the 'top' or 'transformMatrix' didn't work.

Can't I use 'top' or 'transformMatrix' in the "styles" parameter ?

How can I change the position of one character ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So from the use of textDecoration property i guess you are on the 1.7 or similar version.

You should really move to the 2.0 version that has integrated support for multibyte languages and composition.

Said that, there is no support for vertical text in fabricjs at all.
This may change in the future.
You should really go here:

```
https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/511
```

refresh the request and maybe add some detail about it, because the actual mantainer may have no clue on how vertical text should work regarding input, decorations, multiple columns and so on.

Comment: Thank you for your information.  I know I shoud move to the 2.0 version, but I hesitate to move  it because there are few documents of the 2.0 version. Anyway, thank you for your reply.

Comment: Just remember that if you want it to happen, the information of a vertical text user is necessary.